# Rinkeby Network transferred reald funds from exchange

Tags: transactions, rinkeby

I made by mistake a transfer from an exchange to an Rinkeby test network that is not appearing to my Testnet wallet.

This is the transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa09c745269e3b3c5ba76c8d667c859f4e54510150e5145699247267b9ff51edc

Is there some way to make this back to my real ether wallet.

I see the rinkeby wallet but I cannot see the ether funds?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the mainnet using the rinkeby wallet (0xd5799226bd15aca0f961b91b066269af40cd6628).

If your wallet(private key) is same, you should have the same address.

Comment: I think that the key is the same. How do I connect to main net. I do it like this, I switch using the ether wallet GUI to the Development-Mainnetwork, and then I see two other addresses. But I am not sure how to use this one RInkeby Address that had the transactio. Over GUI or over Internet?

Comment: I imported the backuped key file inside the mainnetwork and I see now three accounts under etherum wallet. I see also this one - 0xd5799226bd15aca0f961b91b066269af40cd6628     This is a good sign. But these accounts only showing stil 0.00 ETHER. I started to create now a wallet. Could this work?

Comment: I suggest you use services like [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/). Your wallet may not be up-do-date.